# How do you choose loops for the loop circuit method?

Tags: algorithm, mesh-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, circuit-analysis

**I need to understand how to choose loops for the loop current method of circuit analysis; ideally I'd like to be able to do it by means of an algorithm, so a vague intuition isn't sufficient. Can someone please clarify exactly how this works for me, in terms of necessary and sufficient rules and/or an algorithmic solution?**

The only explanation I seem able to find is the pair of rules (1) "make sure every element is included in a loop or mesh" and (2) "make sure at least one element in each loop is not part of any other loop or mesh". These do not suffice to correctly choose loops, as is evident in the following trivial planar example, where the choice on the left clearly satisfies them:

[image: Voltage source and three resistors in parallel, choice of loops through left and right faces, omitting the middle face, satisfies both rules]

Moreover, there are situations where a clearly sane loop selection fails to satisfy (2), for instance almost any choice including the central mesh as a loop in this example (including the standard choice of using the 5 meshes):

[image: A square with resistors on all sides and each pair of adjacent vertices connected by a second resistor in parallel, except for one pair which is connected by a voltage source]

In this example I've included a weird alternative "solution" which satisfies both rules, but it won't be valid, since it involves only two loops which share no elements. Presumably (2) is just a heuristic for ensuring independent equations and not actually necessary, but that doesn't help me know what IS necessary.

O glorious lords of the electronics stack exchange, please save this lowly and ignorant brother!

Comment: There's a well established theory on this. It's called topology and uses graphs to describe electrical networks. Basically you can choose any tree in your graph to write  a set of indipendent loop equations. I'd just Wiki on topology or graphs

Comment: Julian, just to add to your troubles, there isn't a single answer. For most networks, there exists a set of valid combinations from among all possible permutations with a count larger than 1. It's rare that there is only one way to cut it. You may be able to work out an algorithm that always finds one of them and then stops with what may seem to some of us to be a rather random choice or else you will need to compose all of the possibilities and then develop a weighting algorithm to sort them and select the "most pleasing" in some fashion.

Comment: Julian, I gave it a couple of minutes thought. I believe it must be the case that each loop is unique, all circuit elements must be covered by at least one loop, and there must be a way to traverse from any component to any other component in the schematic by way of shifting from one loop to another loop only where a component is shared by both loops. You can move from component to component within a loop, freely. But you cannot consider yourself moving to a new loop without first stopping on a component shared by two (or more) loops and then mentally considering yourself on a chosen new loop.

Comment: Julian, another thought arises. Every loop ***must*** contain at least one component not in another loop.

Comment: I'll argue with @Jonk.  If you take small clockwise loops with each component seeing two currents in opposite directions, there is one solution.  I'd use last of your 3 loops and none of your 5 loops.

Comment: @jonk I don't think every loop MUST contain at least one component not in another loop, since the standard mesh analysis selection of loops for example (2) violates that. I expect the actual requirement for independent equations is something more like "each loop must contain an element unique to that loop OR must provide a locally necessary connection between two other loops", where by "locally necessary" I mean that if you held the other loop choices constant and dropped the loop under consideration, the graph of loops would no longer be connected (i.e. traversable by component-hopping).

Comment: @jonk But I'm just guessing based on what seems reasonable. I still don't KNOW what conditions are actually required or why.

Comment: @JulianKintobor I've been thinking about an approach -- clued in by something I've read. Look up "spanning tree." It really seems pretty easy, now that I've looked at a few examples. None of those I've seen specify the necessary and sufficient conditions. But I'll arrive at that on my own, now that I understand the use of flattening the schematic onto a plane/sphere with non-crossing loops and how a spanning tree is used. You should look that up. If I pull together enough of the mental image, I'll write it up. Either way, this is fun enough that I'll stay with it as time allows.

Comment: @jonk THAT looks extremely promising! A spanning tree would give us one loop for each edge left out of the tree, and those loops should suffice to solve the circuit... Example 1 has a single-edge spanning tree and 3 loops, so that pathology is handled properly by the spanning tree method. Incidentally, in the loops constructed that way, (2) would be satisfied (assuming you ban diagrams connecting two reference nodes without a circuit element) even though it's not necessary for a valid solution. Flattening won't always be viable though since the loop method can be used on non-planar circuits.